# How to insert spatial data in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, api, spatial, spatial-query

I want to save my coordinate from my Android application to a MySQL database. For this I created an API in PHP, but my code is not working.

**Here is my PHP code:**

```
<?php
  include_once 'db.php';

  $nop = $_POST['nop'];
  $plot_bng = $_POST['plot_bng'];

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sp_house (geom, d_nop)
                                VALUES (STGeomFromText('POINT($plot_bng)'), '$nop')");

  echo json_encode(array("value"=>1));

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I try an INSERT query in phpMyadmin, the data is successfully stored in the database.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-types.html -- mainly look at the data format

Comment: Are you sure you have data in `$nop` and `$plot_bng`? And if you just simply try to insert data into the database without any kind of inspection you are widely open to SQL Injection. Try using `prepared statements` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` before interacting with the database!

Answer (score 2):

**Check the right property for the columns**

First of all, make sure you have created the right spatial columns in the database by using the `GEOMETRY` keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE sp_house (geom GEOMETRY, d_nop VARCHAR(255));
```

**Insert data into the database with authentication**

After you created the columns with the right property you can insert the data into your database. However, your code is widely open to `SQL Injection` and other kind of database hackings since you insert data directly without any kind of authentication. In order to avoid it, use `prepared statements` and the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. *Also, check that you have the right syntax for the query and replace `STGeomFromText` to `ST_GeomFromText`.*

```
<?php
  include_once 'db.php';

  $nop = $_POST['nop'];
  $plot_bng = $_POST['plot_bng'];

  // You can also check that the variables are empty or not ...

  // Clean the variables and prepare for inserting
  $plot_bng = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $plot_bng);
  $nop = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nop);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sp_house (geom, d_nop)
                                VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(POINT(?)), ?)";

  // Prepared statement for inserting
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); // prepare statement for inserting
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$plot_bng,$nop); // replace question marks with values
  $stmt->execute(); // execute command
  $stmt->close(); // close connection

  echo json_encode(array("value"=>1));

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Reference and further reading**

[Creating Spatial Columns in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-columns.html)
[Populating Spatial Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html)
[How to avoid SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
[How to use prepared statements?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: only geom is a geometry data type. I will try your code,
In code  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$plot_bng,$nop);
what is that >> "ss" ?

Comment: First of all, read the reference that is below the code, then you will get an overall knowledge about prepared statements. To answer your question, `s` stands for `string` type `i` stands for integer type `d` stands for `double` and `b` statnds for `BLOB`.

Comment: It means that the two variables `$plot_bng` and `$nop` are both of `string` types. It is a necessary parameter for the `bind_param` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing your var correctly, try like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sp_house (geom, d_nop)
VALUES (STGeomFromText('POINT(".$plot_bng.")'), '".$nop."')");
```

As you writing it, the vars are just normal text...

Comment: I just tried your code, and I testing in postman, status in postman "200 OK", but when I check my DB, i didn't find new data inserted.

Comment: You will always get "200 OK" ass you sending always json_encode(array("value"=>1)) out...

Comment: Include a check
`if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else { echo json_encode(array("value"=>1)); }`